# .on() method in jQuery 1.9 does not work after upgrading from .live() method in version 1.8

Tags: jquery

I am trying to upgrade jQuery program from version 1.8 to 1.9. In earlier version .live() method worked fine but new .on() method does not. The parameter "KenID" sent to the web service retrieving data is "undefined" and hence no data is returned. This parameter is set as sessionStorage item so I guess the .on() method does not have an access to it. What steps should I take to make it work?

Working program (jQuery 1.8):

```
$('#AddrList').live('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data)
    {
        alert(sessionStorage.KenID);    // shows correct KenID
        $.ajax({ 
            // extracting required data by sending KenID to the web service
        });
});
```

NOT working program (jQuery 1.9):

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#AddrList', function (e, data)
    {
        alert(sessionStorage.KenID);    // shows "undefined"
        $.ajax({
            // extracting required data by sending KenID to the web service
        });
});
```

Thank you,
Jacek

Comment: It shows `sessionStorage.KenID` as `undefined` in `jquery.on function` means that this function is called. Check `sessionStorage.KenID` value is set or not before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have two simple question to be asked.

1. Are you sure `#AddrList` is your page's id?
2. Are you sure you set the value already before navigating to the current page for `sessionStorage.KenID`?

if your answer is yes to both questions I asked above then it should work fine.

Here is a <kbd>**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/PwEQr/)**</kbd>

Comment: I am sure about page id - it is correct. However the sessionStorage.KenID is set here `code`$('#KantoList li').on('click', function ()
        {
            var anchor = $(this).find('a');
            sessionStorage.KenID = anchor.attr('id');
            alert(sessionStorage.KenID);
            changePage();
        }); `code`

Comment: why don't you log the value in console e.g. `console.log(sessionStorage.KenID);` and check the console before changing the page?

This will tell you whether you properly set the value.

Comment: Thanks, your second question lead me to the solution.  Another .on() method, one that selected KenID was not properly formatted.  It still used  $('#KantoList li').on('click', function)  instead of   $(document).on('click', '#KantoList li', function);